# :remote=>true not doing AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

EDIT: I changed the code slightly.

I know this is a repeated question here, but I was not able to find the one that fits my problem. I think I am missing something, but I am not able to guess what.

I have a form to create some elements in my app, but I want that form to be executed with `:remote => true`

Form rendered in `events/edit.html.erb`. This form is to create `event_criteria_options`

```
<%= form_for(@event_criteria_option, :remote => true) do |f| %>    
... 
<% end %>
```

This is the create action in `event_criteria_options_controller.rb`

```
def create
  @event_criteria_option = EventCriteriaOption.new(params[:event_criteria_option])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @event_criteria_option.save
      format.html { redirect_to edit_event_path(Event.find(session[:event_id]), :notice => 'Event criteria option was successfully created.') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @event_criteria_option, :status => :created, :location => @event_criteria_option }
      format.js 
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @event_criteria_option.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      format.js 
    end
  end
end
```

and a js.erb file called `create.js.erb`

```
$('#show_event_criteria').html('<%=raw escape_javascript(render(:partial => "show_event_criteria")) %>');
```

`rails.js`, `applicationl.js` and `jquery.js` files are included in the page, but **when the form is submitted is doing HTML call, not AJAX**. I checked the HTML code and `data-remote="true"` exists in the form. I have other forms submiting with `:remote => true` in the app and they work well. I’m using Rails 3.0.1 and Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: I'm having the same issue with my create method.  I'm only wanted to respond to `js` and not `html`, so I'm getting an UnknownFormat error (Rails 4) because of the same reason you were having the issue: it is being requested via html even though my form has `data-remote="true"`.  Any luck with this since you last looked at this?

Comment: @JakeSmith No, I am completing more urgent tasks. If I manage to solve the problem I will put here :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your javascript should be in `update.js.erb` since that is the action your form will post to?

**UPDATE:**

You also need to detect whether it is an ajax call in your update method so that the controller handles everything correctly:

```
if request.xhr?
  # respond to Ajax request
else
  # respond to normal request
end
```

Comment: I think about your answer and it made me rethink and change the code. Anyway, the problem is that even the `:remote = true` is there, the form is submitted with HTML.

Comment: Updated my answer for the missing piece in your controller

Comment: I tried it, just in case, but no luck. The main problem is not that the controller is handling the request incorrectly. **The problem is that the request is HTML, not JS**.`Processing by EventCriteriaOptionsController#create as HTML` should be `Processing by EventCriteriaOptionsController#create as JS`. The controller responds to an HTML request... obviously.

Comment: I know, but the main problem is not that. As far as I know, the request header's content-type should be text/javascript in order to process like JS. The header's type the app is generating (checked with firebug): `Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8`. I may be misunderstanding something, correct me if it is wrong.

Comment: The request from the website is an HTTP request. You're posting the form. The only difference is that its posted by javascript in the page rather than a browser submitting the form.

Answer (score 1):

3 years late to the party but I have come accross this problem as well.  For remote true to submit xhr requests, you need to have the rails jquery gem installed.  HOWEVER, in your application.js file, you need to require BOTH: 

`//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs`

the ujs is the bit that made remote true work with xhr requests.   Mind.  Blown.